# uploading a file via AJAX/FormData using coldfusion on the back end

Tags: ajax, forms, post, encoding, coldfusion

I'm trying to allow users to upload documents to my server. I am being forced to use coldfusion MX 7 on the back end.

I am using the `FormData` constructor and sending the file via ajax.

Here's the client side code that constructs the form and sends the data. The variable `f` is the `File` object I want to upload.

```
_submit: function (e) {
    var f = this.$.agenda.file;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('upload', f);
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (req.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(req)
      }
    }.bind(this);
    req.open("POST", "validator.cfc?method=uploadfile");
    req.send(data);
  }
});
```

this is the `cfcomponent`/`cffunction` that should be doing the work on the server side:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
  <cffunction name="uploadfile" access="remote" returnType="string">
    <cffile action="upload" filefield="upload" 
     destination="data/" 
     nameconflict="makeunique"
     result="uploadResult">
    <cfreturn uploadResult>
  </cffunction>
```

When I try to use it though, I get a cold fusion error stating:

```
String index out of range: -20
The error occurred on line 45
43 :     <cffile action="upload" filefield="upload" 
44 :      destination="data/" 
45 :      result="uploadResult">
46 :     <cfreturn uploadResult>
47 :   </cffunction>
```

what am I doing wrong here, can anyone help out?

Comment: What does `f` contain before this call `data.append('upload', f);` ?

Comment: @Miguel-F Ahh! F wasn't actually the file. I was accidentally just grabbing the file name. Now, F points to the file (the code in the question remains unchanged) but I am getting a new error. I'm editing the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I had to change the `destination` parameter to use the full path.

Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of that enctype being the default, you still may need to explicitly set it in the form:

```
<form action="yourActionPage.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I apologize, This was not the issue, please see my edit and my comment to @Miguel-F. This answer should probably be deleted.